# Applescript created in 10.9 is not opening on 10.10

Tags: macos, applescript

I created an Applescript app (.app) on O.S-10.9 and it working fine.
When I copied that to 10.10 (Yosemite), it will no longer open.

When I double click on Applescript, it is showing following error message:

"You can’t open the application “password” because PowerPC applications are no longer supported."

O.S - Yosemite Beta 10.10

Comment: As you're running a beta OS release, report a bug to Apple.

Comment: Ok, i will do it but there is any solution, so can start my execution.

Comment: Hi guys,  now i am on *yosesmite 10.10.2* then also it is not get open, still it is showing same error please any one can help me.

Comment: It looks like your Applescript calls a PowerPC executable, so it is not going to work. Find out what it calls, then if it runs `/usr/local/bin/program.xyz` you can run `file /usr/local/bin/program.xyz` and you will see that that was made for PowerPC not Intel processors. Then you will need to somehow obtain an Intel executable version of that program.